# Styling td via th?

Tags: html, css, styles, css-tables

I'm not sure if this is possible in HTML5 & CSS3, but is it possible to style a column of cells via its header?

For example, I seem to have seen that the width defined in a header applies to its entire column too.

So is it possible, and if so what's the scope of what's possible via this approach?

Comment: Not related to HTML5 and CSS3 , it's just HTML & CSS thing. Yes, you can style `<th>`, just like `<td>`. What have you tried?

Comment: I haven't exactly tried personally, but from an existing page, I've seen the width defined as percentages in the headers, which affected the cells, but other styles for the header in the css file, such as colour, border, alignment etc did not.

Comment: Try applying CSS to `<th>` and you'll know.